# z-Index Preventing MouseOvers?

Tags: html, css, mouseover, z-index, onmouseover

http://scriptbase.com/scripts/viewer.php  The rounded bottom div is supposed to partially cover the thumbnails for aesthetic effect.  The problem, is, though, that it seems to prevent all mouseovers in those two  (inside the control box and inside the thumbnails wrapper).  What's going wrong here and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you provide some code samples?

Comment: Of what, exactly?  All the relevant code's client side so it's there for the gandering.

Comment: In which browser did any of it work? I'm not getting any mouseovers at all. You also probably don't want your thumbnail <ul> to have `display:inline`. That makes it an inline element and gives it the height of a line box.

Answer (score 0):

Z-indexing is cryptic.  Seems to me that setting the negative z-index on '.thumbs' is enough.  Simply remove the z-index declaration on '.controls' and they come back to life. (You probably also want to remove the resulting top-border aswell).